# How to separate data on on google sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Currently I have this data format on my google sheet:

SKU: PORK BARREL (PILGRIMS/SOBI), QTY: 20000, PRICE PER KILO: 225

[image]

Then I want format my Data like this

[image]

Then I tried to format it using appscript this code

```
/**
 * Multiplies an input value by 2.
 * @param {number} input The number to double.
 * @return The input multiplied by 2.
 * @customfunction
*/
function DOUBLE(input) {
  return input * 2;
}
function result(range) {
  delimiter = ":"
  targetColumn = 19

  var output2 = [];
  for(var i=0, iLen=range.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    var s = range[i][targetColumn].split(delimiter);    
    for(var j=0, jLen=s.length; j<jLen; j++) {
      var output1 = []; 
      for(var k=0, kLen=range[0].length; k<kLen; k++) {
        if(k == targetColumn  ) {
          output1.push(s[j]);
        } else {
          output1.push(range[i][k]);
        }
      }
      output2.push(output1);
    }    
  }
  return output2;
}
```

but my result is like this one
[image]
It goes vertical instead of horizontal.

How can we achieve it like on my desire output to be horizontal and segregate the data.
I also tried to do MID function to split the data but I'm having problem with the QTY , QTY(KG) , QTY(BOX)

I used this code

```
=MID('Form Responses'!T5,Find(":", 'Form Responses'!T5)+1,find("QTY", 'Form Responses'!T5)-10-Find(":", 'Form Responses'!T5)+20)
```

[image]

I also shared my google sheet here for reference since some of data are not matched from my screenshot

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HqOjb4IJPkcpZNZ1No-Tx7WBk7yklz2Iyxjx37ktLao/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Can You Try this -

```
function result(range) {
  delimiter = ":"
  targetColumn = 19

  var output2 = [];
  
  // Add header row
  var headerRow = ["SKU", "QTY", "PRICE"];
  output2.push(headerRow);
  
  for (var i = 0, iLen = range.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    var s = range[i][targetColumn].split(delimiter);
    
    var skuValue = s[0].trim();
    var qtyValue = s[1].trim();
    var priceValue = s[2].trim();
    
    var output1 = [skuValue, qtyValue, priceValue];
    
    output2.push(output1);
  }
  
  return output2;
}
```

1. I added a header row ("SKU", "QTY", "PRICE") as the first element in the output2 array.
2. Within the loop, I split the SKU data into three separate values: SKU Value, QTY Value, and PRICE Value using the delimiter.
3. I constructed a new array output1 for each row with the SKU Value, QTY Value, and PRICE Value.
4. I pushed the output1 array into the output2 array for each row.
5. The output2 array now contains the header row and the formatted data rows in the desired format.

Comment: Hello Prakash, thanks for your response but some of the data are not align,

I can share you my sheet for your reference .

Answer (score 0):

Since I only had one line of text data I just repeated it.

```
function lfunko() {
  let arr = ["SKU: PORK BARREL (PILGRIMS/SOBI), QTY: 20000, PRICE PER KILO: 225", "SKU: PORK BARREL (PILGRIMS/SOBI), QTY: 20000, PRICE PER KILO: 225", "SKU: PORK BARREL (PILGRIMS/SOBI), QTY: 20000, PRICE PER KILO: 225", "SKU: PORK BARREL (PILGRIMS/SOBI), QTY: 20000, PRICE PER KILO: 225"];
  let b = []
  arr.forEach((r, i) => {
    let a = r.split(",");
    let o = {};
    a.forEach(e => {
      let t = e.split(":");
      o[t[0].trim()] = t[1].trim();
    });
    if (i == 0) b.push(Object.keys(o))
    b.push(Object.values(o))
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(b));
  })
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  sh.clearContents();
  sh.getRange(1,1,b.length,b[0].length).setValues(b);
}
```

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SKU | QTY | PRICE PER KILO |
| 2 | PORK BARREL (PILGRIMS/SOBI) | 20000 | 225 |
| 3 | PORK BARREL (PILGRIMS/SOBI) | 20000 | 225 |
| 4 | PORK BARREL (PILGRIMS/SOBI) | 20000 | 225 |
| 5 | PORK BARREL (PILGRIMS/SOBI) | 20000 | 225 |

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"SKU: (.+?), QTY: ()(\d+), PRICE.*?: (\d+)")
```